# BeautifulSoup, extracting strings within HTML tags, ResultSet objects

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am confused exactly how I can use the ResultSet object with BeautifulSoup, i.e. `bs4.element.ResultSet`.

After using `find_all()`, how can one extract text?

Example:

In the `bs4` documentation, the HTML document `html_doc` looks like:

```
<p class="story">
    Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">
     Elsie
    </a>
    ,
    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">
     Lacie
    </a>
    and
    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link2">
     Tillie
    </a>
    ; and they lived at the bottom of a well.
   </p>
```

One begins by creating the `soup` and finding all `href`,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('a')
```

which outputs

```
 [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>, 
  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]
```

We could also do

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

which outputs

```
http://example.com/elsie
http://example.com/lacie
http://example.com/tillie
```

I would like to get *only* the text from the `class_="sister"`, i.e.

```
Elsie
Lacie
Tillie
```

One could try

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get_text())
```

but this results in an error:

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do a `find_all()` filtering on `class_='sister'`.

***Note:*** Notice the **underscore** after `class`.  It's a special case because class is a reserved word.

> It’s very useful to search for a tag that has a certain CSS class, but
>   the name of the CSS attribute, “class”, is a reserved word in Python.
>   Using class as a keyword argument will give you a syntax error. As of
>   Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you can search by CSS class using the keyword
>   argument `class_`:

*Source:* http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

Once you have all of the tags with class sister, call `.text` on them to get the text.  Be sure to strip the text.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''<p class="story">
    Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">
     Elsie
    </a>
    ,
    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">
     Lacie
    </a>
    and
    <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link2">
     Tillie
    </a>
    ; and they lived at the bottom of a well.
   </p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
sistertags = soup.find_all(class_='sister')
for tag in sistertags:
    print tag.text.strip()
```

Output:

```
(bs4)macbook:bs4 joeyoung$ python bs4demo.py
Elsie
Lacie
Tillie
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks. I was confused as "sistertags.text" was throwing an error