# Beautiful soup and regex

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing a page using beautiful soup. I am trying to find and extract an email address which is also hyperlinked on a page.

So far ive tried the code below but it returns the entire  tag while im just trying to extract the text part of the tag. i.e what_im_trying_to_extract@something.com. The email address on the page is the only thing with an @ symbol.

```
soup.select("a[href*=@]")
returns: [<a class="hrTbp " href="mailto:something@something.com">what_im_trying_to_extract@something.com</a>]
```

what im trying to extract is  what_im_trying_to_extract@something.com

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup, extracting strings within HTML tags, ResultSet objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510881/beautifulsoup-extracting-strings-within-html-tags-resultset-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
soup.select("a[href*=@]")[0].text
```